# knife ec2 unknown region "ca-central-1"

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef-infra, knife

I'm trying to create an AWS server in the region "Canada(Central)", which, according to the Amazon documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html), is called ca-central-1.

The command I'm running is:

`knife ec2 server create -I ami-70299b14 -f t2.nano -S my-key -i ~/.ssh/my-key.pem  -ssh-user ubuntu --region ca-central-1 -Z ca-central-1a`

And the error I get is:

`ERROR: ArgumentError: Unknown region: "ca-central-1"`

The ami I'm using is one that I've used to launch a server in the region using the online EC2 Management Console.

I created an IAM user and kay pairs in this region and have given the user all permissions on ec2 resources, and I've also created an inbound rule for ssh in the region. Is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `fog-aws` only added this region very recently so there isn't yet support for it in `knife ec2`. Will hopefully be in the next ChefDK release in a few weeks. For now you can just create VMs either from the `aws` command line tool or the web UI, and then use `knife bootstrap` on them.

Answer (score 0):

1: your knife.rb as

```
knife[:aws_access_key_id] = "AWS_ACCESS_KEY"
knife[:aws_secret_access_key] = "AWS_SECRET"
knife[:ssh_key_name] = 'my-key'
knife[:image] = 'ami-21414f36'
knife[:flavor] = 't2.micro'
knife[:region] = 'ca-central-1'
knife[:availability_zone] = 'ca-central-1a'
knife[:ebs_size] = 30
knife[:editor] = 'nano'
```

2: Generate Key Pair for Canada (Center)

3: Run the knife ec2 server create command.

```
 knife ec2 server create -I ami-70299b14 -f t2.nano  -ssh-user ubuntu --region ca-central-1 -Z ca-central-1a
```

That's worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this command:

```
knife ec2 server create -N node_name -I ami-21414f36 -f t2.micro -x '.\key_ca'  -P 'ec2@123' --ssh-key key --region ca-central-1 --availability-zone 'ca-central-1a' --ebs-size 30 --security-group-ids sg-75cbd50d --bootstrap-protocol winrm --winrm-transport ssl --winrm-ssl-verify-mode verify_none
```